# How to add aspect ratio of the view with visual format language?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, visual-format-language

I am creating the view dynamically. I want to set the view's aspect ratio using visual format language. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is impossible:

> Most of the Auto Layout constraints you'll use can be expressed with the Visual Format Language. There are a few that can't, however. For
>   instance, a fixed aspect ratio constraint cannot be created using the
>   Visual Format Language. This can't be accomplished with the Visual
>   Format Language syntax, because the following string can't be parsed:
>
> H:|imageView.width = 2 * imageView.height|
>
> You can still use Auto Layout in your code to achieve these types of
>   constraints using the traditional constraintWithItem method.

[Whole article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-visual-format-language--cms-22715)